# Step function between two alternating values

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I'm looking to plot connectivity over time to see connection duration and amount of disconnects. Here is the graph I currently have.

[image]

This graph is misleading though. It makes it seem like the machine is slowly disconnecting between Sep 29th and Oct 3rd when it reality it is connected that whole time before a brief disconnection.

I'd like the line to remain at 1 / connected until it is not connected.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Tableau is doing this because it draws a line between all data points in the view along the x-axis.  I'm assuming you don't have a 1 before October 3rd, so it just slowly slopes to the next point which happens to be a 0.

There are few approaches you could use to visualize this type of data.  If the system is always connected, when not disconnected, then you could just visualize points that are disconnects.  Additionally, switching to a bar plot may sometimes communicate your intent better than a line in this situation.

Depending on the structure, and assumptions of how the disconnected/connects are ordered in your underlying data, you could create a table calculation that uses the last value in the partition to determine it's value.  (connected vs. disconnected)

You could also resample the data to turn your irregular time series into something that is regular.  This would add a large number of data points, depending on the time interval you are looking for. (1 million for 15 days at 1 second)

Comment: Unfortunately the data is not very regular. There can be many connect messages before a disconnect message and vice versa. I'll look into using the last value

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Clarify the units on your x-axis: days? hours? secs?
2. Try using dots instead of a line connector
3. 2. & Flip the visualization around: plot a transform of your data where 'connected'=0 and 'disconnected'=1

Comment: 1. That field is a timestamp, so DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Right now I am using Exact date.  2. I've attempted dots, but it doesn't provide the same effect.  3. I will try that.

Comment: Inverting it resulted in essentially the same effect but upside down

Comment: The main answer, which @tyvich also mentions is: don't use a line connector.